# Tkinter multitabbed UI with dynamically created widgets - Not sure if this is even possible

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tabs, widget

I am working on a multi tabbed UI that is planned to have N standalone tabs created for DB search queries.( Note that N is undefined and user can create as many tabs as they want..)
Each DB search query will have same types of the widgets BUT the search key and other filters will be different (depending on the tab). A user should have a capability of having several queries and being able to navigate across without a need to refresh the content (i.e. without a need to re-run search function).

My current problem is that the code below doesn't produce the expected outcome but instead creates a single set of widgets (buttons, entry & list box) displayed on all tabs vs creating independent set of widgets mapped to newly created tab.

One of the reasons why I have chosen tkinter is that because it has frames and I wanted the UI to be scalable i.e. wanted to be able reposition widgets when the window is maximized.

-----------Code Snippet------------------------

```
`import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

clstk = tk.Tk()

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#entries
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
entry_search_key = tk.StringVar()
entry_dir_out_path = tk.StringVar()
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# labels:
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
lbl_dir_input_path = tk.StringVar()
lbl_search_for = tk.StringVar()

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#colors
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

frame_bg_color='#EBE8F4'
btn_bg_color='#F8F7F7'



dict_config_params = dict([
    ('var_def_search_key', 'search key'),
    ])


class main(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.parent)
        self.setup_ui()


    def setup_ui(self):

        self.set_window_geometry()
        self.create_menu()



    def set_window_geometry(self):

        #set grid layout for the entire window
        # 1 column and 3 rows and weights for scaling up
        
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.parent, 0, weight=1)
        
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.parent, 0, weight=0)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.parent, 1, weight=0,minsize=75)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.parent, 2, weight=1)

        self.notebook.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.W)
        self.notebook.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)


    def create_tabs(self):


        tab_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        idx = self.notebook.index('end')

        self.notebook.add(tab_frame, text ='Query #: '+str(idx+1),sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)

        self.add_btn_frame(tab_frame)
        self.add_list_frame(tab_frame, idx)        
  

    def add_btn_frame(self,tab1):

        #this method is to create frames to ensure widgets aren't overlapped when resizing window

        mainFrame = tk.Frame(tab1,bg='blue').grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3)
        #mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")

        labelsearchText = tk.Label(mainFrame,bg=frame_bg_color,
                                        textvariable=lbl_search_for)
        lbl_search_for.set(" Search for: ")
        labelsearchText.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky="w")


        searchEntry = tk.Entry(mainFrame,
                                 textvariable=entry_search_key,width=50)
        entry_search_key.set(dict_config_params['var_def_search_key'])
        searchEntry.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky="w", padx= 80)

        button = tk.Button(mainFrame, text="search", width=10,bg=btn_bg_color,
                       command=self.search_routine)
        button.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky="w", padx= 400)


    def add_list_frame(self, tabFrame,idx):

        #this method is to create frames to ensure widgets aren't overlapped when resizing window

        mainFrame = tk.Frame(tabFrame,).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=3)

        listbox = tk.Listbox(mainFrame)
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(listbox, orient="vertical",command=listbox.yview)
        listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        listbox.grid(row=2, column=0,padx=5, sticky="nsew")
        #tab1.append(listbox)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        listbox.insert("end", "Welcome to search" + str(idx))

    def add_sb_frame(self):
        mainFrame = tk.Frame(self.parent,).grid(row=2, columnspan=1, padx=3)


    def create_menu(self):
        
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent) 

        menu_search = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff =0)
        menu_report = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff =0)
        menu_settings = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff =0)
        menu_exit = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff =0)

        menubar.add_cascade(label='Search', menu=menu_search)
        menu_search.add_command(label = 'New Search', command=self.new_search)

        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)    

    def new_search(self):
        self.create_tabs()



    def search_routine(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Open Report", "Code is in works..")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':

    run = main(clstk)
    clstk.mainloop()`
```

Attached screenshots is the best way to describe what i was expecting,  but current code obviously produces only single set of 3 widgets that is shown on all tabs and there is no way to put a different key for the specific tab. The idea of repositioning widget wouldn't work as then I will loose content shown on different tabs and while I can save a value from the entry into the variable, it will be impossible to save content of N different lists and have all that info being repopulated.

Not sure if this UI is even possible using Tkinter and/or if there is a better library to achieve this goal.

[image: Search Query #1]

[image: Search Query #2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is very doable with tkinter, but you need to use the right architecture to make it easy. In a nutshell, create a class for the search tab, and then create as many instances as you want.

The following example illustrates the technique. It defines a class for a tab, a menubar with a menu that lets you add new tabs, and then auto-creates the first tab. You can create as many tabs as you want via the menu.

Note: this isn't necessarily the best solution. You could, for example, move `add_tab` into the `Menubar` class or some other class, you could move `do_search` into main or some other class, you could make `Main` a subclass of a `tk.Frame` instead of `tk.Tk` so you could have multiple windows in addition to multiple tabs, and so on.

None of that is really relevant to the core question of how to dynamically create tabs so I picked a fairly simple implementation.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class SearchTab(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Search for:")
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=40)
        self.search_button = ttk.Button(self, text="search", command=self.do_search)
        self.results = tk.Listbox(self)
        self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.results.yview)
        self.results.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
        self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew")
        self.results.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.vsb.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky="ns")

        # use an invisible column to take up all extra space
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

        # the second row should fill the frame vertically
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def do_search(self):
        querystring = self.entry.get()
        self.results.delete(0, "end")

        # simulate some results...
        for i in range(20):
            self.results.insert("end", f"Result #{i+1} for '{querystring}'")

class Menubar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, main, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(main, **kwargs)

        self.search_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.search_menu.add_command(label="Add Tab", command=main.add_tab)

        self.add_cascade(label="Search", menu=self.search_menu)

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.menubar = Menubar(self)
        self.configure(menu=self.menubar)

        # add the first tab; the user can add more via the menubar
        self.add_tab()

    def add_tab(self):
        new_tab = SearchTab(self.notebook)
        tab_number = int(self.notebook.index("end")) + 1

        self.notebook.add(new_tab, text=f"Query #{tab_number}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much Bryan. That's exactly what I was trying to get to.  I wish there was some good source of documentation or more examples on implementing Tkinter UI in custom classes. But in the future, I'll try to use similar approach so thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Disclaimer: this code was generated through a few iterations of an LLM. I tested it and read it and it looks okay, but **caution is advised**.</sub>

This is pretty close to what's in your concept pictures, I'm not entirely sure if this is exactly what you meant but it might be useful to you.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():

    # Create instance
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Add a title
    root.title("Tkinter GUI with Tabs")

    # Create tab control
    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

    # Create the tabs
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

    # Add the tabs to the tab control
    tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
    tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')

    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    # Define layout and widgets for Tab 1
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(tab1)
    entry1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew')

    button1 = ttk.Button(tab1, text="Search")
    button1.grid(column=1, row=0)

    listbox1 = tk.Listbox(tab1)
    listbox1.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
    listbox1.insert(tk.END, "Welcome to Search")  # Insert text into listbox

    # Configure the grid
    tab1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    tab1.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # Define layout and widgets for Tab 2
    entry2 = ttk.Entry(tab2)
    entry2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ew')

    button2 = ttk.Button(tab2, text="Search")
    button2.grid(column=1, row=0)

    listbox2 = tk.Listbox(tab2)
    listbox2.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
    listbox2.insert(tk.END, "Welcome to Search 2")  # Insert text into listbox

    # Configure the grid
    tab2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    tab2.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # Start the main loop
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The trick here is that number of tabs in my code is not a constant. User should be able to create as many tabs as they need for the search queries and that particular nuance changes everything from the UI design perspective. I understand that when you create 2 different objects (tab1 and tab2) the code works fine, but when tabs are created dynamically and frames are mapped to each of those the outcome changes completely.